# Xcode 3 Product depends on itself. Audio Unit Effects copy file issue

Tags: xcode, macos, core-audio, audiounit

For reasons beyond my control, I am using Xcode 3 and attempting to build a crude Audio Unit effect. While setting up the configuration for my project, I tried to set up a 'Copy Files' build phase in order to have the Component Manager be able to find my unit. When I dragged the Unit's component into the new Copy Files build phase and tried to to build the project, I am getting the follow error:

`Check Dependencies: Product depends on itself. THis target might include it's own product.`

I tried deleting the component file from my Copy Files build phase, and I was able to build the project successfully, however when I run `auval -a` in the terminal, the Component Manager does not find my effect unit.

How can i fix this?... is it even fixable in Xcode 3?

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish build and install in one build invocation, you can either

a) create a separate target which defines the AU as a dependency and performs the copy (and any other post-build steps)

or b) set the `INSTALL_PATH` to the components directory and `touch` the AU as the last build step